# How this pre hook save works?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to use populate in mongoose, and my current idea is to check if a particular document is present in MongoDB, if it is then, the pre-save hook should check and rather then creating a new Document, it should just push it to the refs, so that I can populate later.

Now, the ref is being saved in MongoDB, however, how to check if the document which I am trying to save is there in mongo in pre save(or any other more suitable method)

This is the schema.

```
var Userschmea  = new mongoose.Schema({
  user:String,
  posts:[{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Post'
  }]
})


var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content:String,
  author:[{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Author'
  }]
})

Userschmea.pre('save',(next)=>{
  //what to do here
  next()
})


var Post = mongoose.model('Post',PostSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User',Userschmea);
```

This is the endPoint by which I am trying to save:

```
app.post('/save/user',(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);

  //Can i access this in my pre-save
  const newUser  = new User({
    user: req.body.user
  })

  newUser.save((err)=>{

    const newPost = new Post({
      content:req.body.content,
      author: newUser._id
    })

    newPost.save((err)=> {
      if(err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }
    })

    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.send(err);
    }

  })
  return res.send(req.body.user);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findOne` method with some unique key to check whether user is exists or not. I have used here `email`.

```js
Userschmea.pre('save',(next)=>{
  var self = this;
  Userschmea.findOne({email : this.email}, 'email', function(err, results) {
    if(err) {
      next(err);
    } else if(results) {
      self.invalidate("user", "user is exists");
      next(new Error("User is already exists"));
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
})
```

Hope this help!

**====== UPDATE =====**

**Q:** `this` is coming empty.

**Ans:**

> Function expressions are best for object methods while Arrow functions are best for callbacks or methods like map, reduce, or forEach.

So, Don't use arrow function in this case to access global scope.

Comment: The "this" is coming empty

Comment: Don't use arrow function for this case, `function(next) {` instead of `(next) => {`

Comment: @AlpitAnand, Agree with above comment. Please find updated answer.

Comment: Just one more thing, i need to save it if its not there, and if its there, i need to push some values is this possible

Comment: If document not found pre save will save document as per current implementation. Second case is if you want to push some values if document exists then you can  handle it by catch exception which will throw while pre hook. Or you can use findOneAndUpdate pre hook.